# MySQL database xampp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

I am trying to make a forum but for that i need a database whit data.
this are my scripts :

(Connect and printdata script)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="frm">
        
            <?php $con = connect(); ?>

<div>
    <?php renderContent($con); ?>
</div>
        
    </div>

</body>
</html>



<?php
    function connect() {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "forum");
        var_dump($con);
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        } else {
            return $con;
        }
    }
    
    function renderContent($con) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM textforum";
        $result = $con->query($sql);
        
        
        
            // output data of each row
            
                echo $row["text"]. "<br>";
            
        
        
    }
```

and the output error is:

> object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(21) "5.5.5-10.1.21-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50505) ["stat"]=> string(134) "Uptime: 7020 Threads: 1 Questions: 1674 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 38 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 30 Queries per second avg: 0.238" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(177) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginTest\Login\process.php on line 42

ankit :
this is my output :
*object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(21) "5.5.5-10.1.21-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50505) ["stat"]=> string(134) "Uptime: 8825 Threads: 1 Questions: 1683 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 38 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 30 Queries per second avg: 0.190" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(182) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
Text blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblbText blalblalblb*

the blalblalblbText is the correct output but the rest not how do i get rid of it.

Comment: Where you call those functions connect() and renderContent($con).?

Comment: Where have you mentioned your database name in connection?

Comment: Use as : $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databaseName");

Comment: i update the script the things dindt work

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect()` accepts 4th argument as `databasename`

1. Hostname
2. Username
3. Password
4. Databasename

You missed to pass the database in your connection

try this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","database_name_here");
```

Update your function `renderContent`:

```
function renderContent($con) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM textforum";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["text"]. "<br>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

Comment: i update your code and look at the new script i get an other error

Comment: i get the output of the updated script and the correct output but how do i get ridth of it

Comment: Sorry! I can't understand what you say.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to fetch the row from results

```
    function renderContent($con) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM textforum";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
           // output data of each row
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row["text"];
          }
        }
```